# Python IDLE won't open with .py file, only from start menu

Tags: python, python-idle

I've looked through many similar questions, but no one seems to have had this same problem.  I can open the IDLE shell perfectly fine from the start menu.  Once in, I can use `File->Open` to open any .py file.

However, my problem is that if I try to open any .py file from File Explorer with IDLE, the files will run, but the IDLE application won't come up.  This especially makes it difficult to quit running when I can't even close the application if it's not open.  It also makes it very tedious if I have to always use `File->Open` from the IDLE shell if I want to open a .py file.  How can I at least get the Edit with IDLE option to come back?

Comment: Your best bet is to delete IDLE from your system, and then re-install it, as his never happened to me before (assuming you are using a Windows system)

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly how you "open with idle" from explorer?

Comment: Also, what's your actual question?

Comment: I tried deleting it all and reinstalling python but it still won't let me open with idle.  By "open with idle" I mean I find the location if the file in file explorer, I right click it, select "Open with", and choose IDLE.  Before, this would open the code so I could edit it, now it only runs the program.

Comment: If you have installed a recent version of Python 3 on Windows and you right-click on a .py file, you should see both `Edit with IDLE >`, which lets you select which installed version you want to *edit* with, and `Open with   >`, which lets you select a program to *run* the file.  Select 'Edit' to edit.

Comment: Once I have IDLE open, I often use Recent files to open files.  If I want to edit a file in the same directory as a file already open, I use file open, cntl-O, in the editor with that file.

Comment: `Open with >` is a default entry on context menus.  I believe that there are system settings that govern its behavior.  In particular, there may be one that says whether to open and run or open and 'edit'.  It is possible that you accidentally changed a setting for `Open with`, perhaps be installing a program that changed it.  `Edit with IDLE` is added by the python.org Windows installer.  No other program should touch it.  (Note: you never said which python version and which installer.)

Comment: Edit with IDLE is also now longer showing.  I reinstalled it using the Windows executable installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, soo annoying. I always had 64 bit python and if I wanted to quickly check/test something I could quickly open the file through idle by right click without going through VS code overkill. Now I dont know what I did but that option isnt there anymore. Even tried setting idle as default `.py` handler but it doesnt work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and came looking for an answer, but ended up figuring it out:
I had the issue when I downloaded the 64-bit version for windows (3.9.7), but the issue was resolved when I instead installed the 32-bit version of 3.9.7.
Now I can right-click > "Edit with IDLE"

Comment: By this point I’ve ditched idle in favor of VS code, which is far superior to IDLE’s old-fashioned appearance and functionality, but thanks for finally providing a valid answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you open the file from within IDLE, you open it in an edit window. If you try to open it from the file explorer, it will RUN it on IDLE. So that's why you can't just "open it" from the explorer.

I suggest that you start using some other tools to code in python. Sublime Text and Atom are great text editors, and both can be used as a python IDE.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, just attempts to sell alternative editors.

Comment: No, there is a question.  Before it worked just fine to select a file from File Explorer and have it open with IDLE and not run, but now it will only run, even if I choose "open with IDLE".  I don't know what changed, but I want to know how to get back to how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be outside of Idle as I had the same behavior on OS 12.6. Restarting the Finder from the Force Quit menu resolved.